# Ionic 3 cordova-plugin-advanced-http Host Mismatch Issue

Tags: cordova, ssl, ionic3, veracode

I am using cordova plugin for SSL pinning in my Ionic 3 based project [cordova-plugin-advanced-http](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-advanced-http)

As per its documentation we have to pass `Hostname` in `setHeader()` function in order to tie it with particular host.

[image]

I have done exactly that and added `Hostname` in `setHeader()` function  and checked at run-time to call an different URL from `setHeader()` field and it does not allow it to go through, hence confirming the SSL pinning is working correctly with matching `Hostname`

```
intitializeSSLPinning() {
    this.http.setRequestTimeout(60);
    this.http.setDataSerializer('json');
    this.http.setSSLCertMode('pinned');
    this.http.setHeader('https://www.example.com:443', 'Content-Type', 'application/json');
 }
```

But in Veracode application security report an medium level issue is raised

> Improper Validation of Certificate with Host Mismatch
>
> The failure to validate host-specific certificate data may mean that, while
>   the certificate read was valid, it was not for the site originally requested.

Can someone please help me identify is the tool generating an false error report or I am missing anything w.r.t correct implementation of SSL Pinning in my application.

Answer (score 0):

I actually don't get what you are trying to achieve. The `setHeader()` method is meant to set a global header. It has nothing to do with the SSL pinning feature.
If you really meant to set a header value, you'll need to provide the hostname, not an URL. In your case it should be `this.http.setHeader('www.example.com', 'Content-Type', 'application/json');`